# Are these variations of complex multiplication studied topics?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, operator-theory, analytic-geometry, binary-operations

Complex multiplication is very well understood geometrically and algebraically, but I wonder what about the following operators -angles assumed to be randians $[0,2\pi)$:

1. Complex multiplication(muladd):  $$ x_1 \cdot x_2 = |x_1||x_2|e^{(\arg(x_1) + \arg(x_2))i}$$
2. Complex mulmul: $$ x_1 \bigodot x_2 = |x_1||x_2|e^{\arg(x_1) \cdot \arg(x_2)i} $$
3. Complex addadd: $$ x_1 \bigoplus x_2 = (|x_1|+|x_2|)e^{(\arg(x_1) + \arg(x_2))i} $$
4. Complex addmul: $$ x_1 \bigotimes x_2 = (|x_1|+|x_2|)e^{(\arg(x_1) \cdot \arg(x_2))i} $$

Have these operators been studied? Are there any books or papers on their properties? Do they have names?

Comment: I'm curious, where did this show up?

Comment: This my way of solving a problem I've been thinking about for over a year. But before I dive in and work out all the details I wanted to know if someone had already studied this so I don't have to spend time working something that has already been worked out.

Comment: These other operations seem very unnatural.

Comment: So did imaginary numbers before Euler. :p

Comment: Hmmm... you do have a point. However, also remember that imaginary numbers were discovered to answer a crucial question, that is whether $x^2+1=0$ has any solutions. Therefore, I think it might be useful if we also get to see what the question you are trying to answer is (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of any of those (besides ordinary complex multiplication) being studied. The problem with the ones that multiply arguments is that usually when taking the arg of a complex number, we get an angle out. Angles are cyclical, so that $2\pi$ is treated the same as 0. But multiplying angles doesn't preserve this cyclical nature. $0 \times \frac{\pi}{2}$ is not the same as $2\pi\times\frac{\pi}{2}$. So those operations will be discontinuous. And finally, addadd is pretty much vector addition.